# Why do I keep booting Asus Expressgate instead of the Ubuntu CD?

Tags: 12.04

I am getting stuck in Express Gate Cloud installed on the netbook Asus and cannot install my Ubuntu OS, Can anyoane help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use ASUS cloud, uninstall it, then retry the **12.04** installation. I have extensive ASUS experience and recommend that everyone remove that "program" when they first get their machine.
If you must keep it, press ESC key after reboot and choose the boot drive from the menu.
If you need more details http://www.ehow.com/how_6787509_boot-usb-eee-pc-netbook.html